# Module report_invoice_salesman for Openerp v7.0

Tags: odoo

In the openerp documentation it has to be mention that the module "report_invoice_salesman" is used for analysing / setting the target for the sales people.

is this module available for openerp v7.0.

or

which module replace this module in openerp v7.0. Please mention the where we can download it.